# Code to create CAPTCHA code in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-2.0

I want to create a CAPTCHA similar to http://www.gigbooks.com/getcaptcha.php this one. But its in PHP an anyone provide me the code to create the same in ASP.NET ?

I am using ASP.NET 2.0 (C#)

Thanks,

Comment: What's so special about this one? Do you have the PHP source code?

Comment: This looks good, and the same i want for my application. I don't have the PHP code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For a programmatic API to reCAPTCHA, start at the [recapture home page](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/).

If you just want to hide contact emails, take a look at Google's [reCAPTCHA mailhide](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin#mailhide).

Comment: What are your objections to recaptcha?

Comment: @Brahma, Recaptcha is a cool captcha but not compatible with Target Frame Work 3.5. I am also searching for one.

Comment: @ShamYemul: Google's clearly not a fan of avoiding link rot. Updated with the current link.

Comment: @BramhaGhosh Objections to Recaptcha: https://www.fastcompany.com/90369697/googles-new-recaptcha-has-a-dark-side